# Prevent JavaScript window.getSelection() circular reference

Tags: javascript, selection, circular-reference

See this demo (dependent on selectionchange event which works in Chrome only at this moment): http://jsfiddle.net/fyG3H/

Select some lorem ipsum text and then focus the text input. In the console log you will see that there is a DOMSelection object.
It has an anchorNode value of `HTMLBodyElement` while it should have one of `Text`.

I didn't know why this was happening until I tried stringfying the selection object: http://jsfiddle.net/fyG3H/1/

This gives the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

**Do you know how I can prevent this circular reference caused by window.getSelection() ?**

**EDIT**

New demo which works in other browsers too but still gives the wrong anchorNode: http://jsfiddle.net/fyG3H/5/

And with JSON.stringify: http://jsfiddle.net/fyG3H/6/

Firefox seem to return an empty {} instead of throwing an error.

Comment: your fiddle is missing json2 js library.

Comment: JSON is a native object in ECMAScript 5. No need to include a library.

Comment: Really? And we all know how many browsers support that... don't we?

Comment: Yes we do: http://robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-native-json.html. However that's not to the point here. Do you actually have an answer on the question?

Comment: Alright, tried on FF5 and IE9. Cannot reproduce. IE9 returns empty object, FF logs `undefined`. Seems like a chrome only issue.

Comment: That is because the selectionchange event works in Chrome only at this moment. I've edited the question with two more cross browsers demos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke `toString()` on `getSelection()`.  I've [**updated your fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fyG3H/8/) to behave as you'd expect.

```
var selection;

$('p').bind('mouseup', function() {
    selection = window.getSelection().toString();
});

$('input').bind('focus', function() {
   this.value = selection;
   console.log(selection); 
});
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fyG3H/8/)

---

**EDIT:**

The reason that you're not getting the correct anchor node is that the `DOMSelection` object is passed by reference and when you focus on the input, the selection gets cleared, thus returning the selection defaults corresponding to no selection.  One way you can get around this is to clone the `DOMSelection` properties to an object and reference that.  You won't have the prototypal `DOMSelection` methods any more, but depending on what you want to do this may be sufficient.

```
var selection, clone;

$('p').bind('mouseup', function() {
    selection = window.getSelection();
    clone = {};
    for (var p in selection) {
        if (selection.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            clone[p] = selection[p];
        }
    }
});

$('input').bind('focus', function() {
   console.dir(clone); 
});
```

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fyG3H/9/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By making a string from the selection object, the object is lost and therefore it isn't an adequate solution.

Comment: Then store the `getSelection()` and call `toString()` on it whenever you want the contents.

Comment: Storing getSelection() is exactly what I'm doing in the demo (http://jsfiddle.net/fyG3H/5/).

Comment: We can probably help better if you explain what you're trying to accomplish with the selection instead of just what's going wrong.

Comment: The output I'm after is a `selection` variable holding the complete DOMSelection object with `selection.anchorNode.parentNode.nodeName`giving `P` instead of `HTML`.

Comment: Updated answer with explanation.

Comment: This is obviously not a very clean solution but it works. So thank you for baring with me and coming up with this answer!