# javascript window.getSelection() circular reference error

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension. I am using `window.getSelection()` method to change the properties of the selected text, but I want to save the DOM of the selected text so that on visiting the site again the extension can retrieve the same text.

Saving `window.getSelection()` gives circular reference error. Is there any other way possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880516/prevent-javascript-window-getselection-circular-reference

Comment: How do you save it? For the DOM, you obviously cannot use JSON serialisation.

Comment: i tried saving it as (var userSelection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);) but i am not able to access the methods of (userselection.commonAncestorContainer).

Comment: @woody i did refer to that link before asking this question but i did not get the answer.

Comment: @flyingmachine That question did give the correct answer: You need to call `.toString()`, like `window.getSelection().toString()`